# Woocommerce storefront theme Product Search Bar to page center

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce, storefront

I have a WordPress e-commerce site [graceamaron.com](https://graceamaron.com/)

in the site a search bar is located at top of the page at right side. But I want it in center. How do I change the order of the columns inside the header using CSS.

Simplified example:

```
header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: firebrick;
  display: flex;
}

.logo,
.search{
  width: 25%;
}
.nav {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```
<header>
  <div class="logo">
    <p>logo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="nav">
    <p>Home contact ...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="search">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search">
  </div>
</header>
```

Present my site screenshot (search bar at right side)

[image]

and this is the way I want (page center)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is WordPress and you are not able to change the HTML layout I've done the following CSS fix.
I added `display: flex` to the wrapper of the 3 blocks inside the header. Then I added order attributes
to the elements to order them to my liking, then I also added width and replaced margin with padding so it doesn't force any element to go on the next line.

```
/* Header Wrapper */
.site-header .col-full {
    display: flex;
}

/* Site Logo */
.site-header .site-branding {
    order: 1;
    width: 25%!important;
    margin-right: 0!important;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

/* Searchfield */ 
.site-header .site-search {
    order: 2;
    width: 50%!important;
    padding-right: 20px;
}


/* Navigation */
.site-header .secondary-navigation {
    order: 3;
    width: 25%!important;
    margin: 0!important;
}
```

Results

[image]

Comment: Hello @Fuziion ,
giving styles by id is not working, I tried to change it from `#site-header` to `.site-header` then it's working.

Comment: Hello @Fuziion I have edited your answer to mark it as ANSWER. Presently it is being reviewed.

Comment: Just noticed I entered the wrong ID, I approved your edit